# Copy from list to textarea but prevent duplicates

Tags: javascript

I have this code, it helps to select values from a list and pass them to a textarea but, I don't want to duplicate in case accidentally pressing the same list value.

Heres is what i got:

```
window.onload = btnsInit;
function btnsInit()
{
  var i, a = document.getElementById('btns').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i].onclick = btnClick;
  }
}
function btnClick(e)
{
  document.getElementById('ta').value += '' + this.firstChild.nodeValue + '\n';
  xPreventDefault(e);
  trim();
  return false;
}
function xPreventDefault(e)
{
  if (e && e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  else if (window.event) window.event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Any idea anyone?

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried any checkings?

```
function btnClick(e)
{     
  if ( (document.getElementById('ta').value).indexOf(this.firstChild.nodeValue) ) < 0
      document.getElementById('ta').value += '' + this.firstChild.nodeValue + '\n';
  xPreventDefault(e);
  trim();
  return false;
} // haven't tested;
```

// FOR DEBUG PURPOSE

```
function btnClick(e)
{     
  console.log((document.getElementById('ta').value).indexOf(this.firstChild.nodeValue));
  console.log("ta =", document.getElementById('ta').value);
  console.log("value =", this.firstChild.nodeValue);
  if ( (document.getElementById('ta').value).indexOf(this.firstChild.nodeValue) ) < 0
      document.getElementById('ta').value += '' + this.firstChild.nodeValue + '\n';
  xPreventDefault(e);
  trim();
  console.log("#end ta =", document.getElementById('ta').value);
  return false;
} // haven't tested;
```

Comment: Nop... Now it selects nothing

Comment: @SamRamSan, that's strange. Have you got any working example (i.e. on http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @SamRamSan, can you try debug version and show what's in your browser's console?

Comment: It gives an error on this line:
if ( (document.getElementById('ta').value).indexOf(this.firstChild.nodeValue) ) < 0

Comment: @SamRamSan copy-paste it here, please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14753/discussion-between-ted-and-sam-ram-san)

Comment: OK... your solution is perfect, the problem was that the ))<0 goes like this ) <0 ) Thanks' a lot. That was very educational :- )